# Google login iOS - "My GIDSignInButton only works in long press"

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, google-signin, gidsignin

The google login button provided by google (GIDSignInButton), is not working in normal press but in long press. Otherwise evrything is normal.
Any idea guys?

Comment: Share code or an example through which others can help you.

Answer (score 1):

That was due to a tap recognizer I had in the same viewcontroller. Issue got solved.

Answer (score 1):

Google sign in default button not works in single tap, it works after 1 
long press because of the Tap Gesture included in same 
viewcontroller...

**So the Solution is Handle touch event in sameViewcontroller:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 let touchRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
#selector(onBaseTapOnly))
    touchRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    touchRecognizer.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(touchRecognizer)
}

func onBaseTapOnly(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .ended {
        //react to tap
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }
}

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return touch.view == gestureRecognizer.view

}
```